# How to get window handle from a CDialog derived class?

Tags: window, handle, cdialog, cwnd

Is there a way to retrieve window handle from a CDialog derived class (like CWnd::m_hWnd member) ?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
HWND hWnd = GetSafeHwnd();
```

Should do the trick, but CDialog is itself derived from CWnd so m_hWnd would be accessable inside CDialog too